# Updating user via System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement library randomly results in 'Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain.' exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices

We've implemented logic using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (.NET Framework 4.5.2) to update user's Enabled flag. The issue is that we are sporadically receiving the following exception on user update:

```
System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131014)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.InternalGetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32 hr, IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis, Boolean fForWinRT)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMHRExceptionObject(Int32 hr, IntPtr pCPCMD, Object pThis)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.PutEx(Int32 lnControlCode, String bstrName, Object vProp)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.OnClearComplete()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.set_Value(Object value)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.AccountControlToDirectoryEntry(Principal p, String propertyName, DirectoryEntry de, String suggestedProperty, Boolean isSAM, Boolean isUnpersisted)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.UserFlagsToWinNTConverter(Principal p, String propertyName, DirectoryEntry de, String suggestedWinNTProperty, Boolean isLSAM)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.PushChangesToNative(Principal p)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.Update(Principal p)
```

Code that throws that exception:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName))
{
    UserPrincipal toUpdate = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, username);

    if (toUpdate.Enabled != active)
    {
        toUpdate.Enabled = active;
        toUpdate.Save();
    }                
}
```

That code runs on Windows Server 2012 R2

We are expecting that code to run consistently without sporadic exceptions.